# Kotlin + Docker - How to get data to my app?

Tags: postgresql, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to coding in kotlin in android studio. I have one table(name: Items(three colums:name, price, date)). Database is postgresql. How do I call http method get and save data in application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution for you it's to create a layer that can communicate by http requests (such a REST API). I suggest you to create a Spring REST API using Spring Boot, because it's easy to do. After that, you just create some HTTP Clients in kotlin for firing http requests to some specific URL.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using docker to virtualization and my controller is created by Blueprint API

Comment: You don't virtualize with Docker, but containerize. It's a difference of flavour. What you are containerising? I think that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Error: The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins.
Here is my build.gradle: https://pastebin.com/uyivF5t6

Comment: Did you install java plugin in Android Studio?

Comment: I have only I18n for Java and Java Bytecode Decompiler plugins

Comment: The REST API using Spring Boot must be created outside the Android Project. It's something separate of the Android mobile app.

Comment: So I can not use Spring boot, is there another REST API or should I use json?

Comment: Spring Boot it's a Java framework, not an Android one. You should develop a Java REST API and call the API from you Android mobile app.